# Block or Disable SVN Dump rights

Tags: svn, subversion-edge

How can I block or disable svn dump command or rights for particular user or all users!

I tried tried to find but unable to find the solution on the same.

Comment: What kind of "dump rights" do you ask about?

Comment: I mean I do not want everyone who has read/write access to perform dump. By dump I mean this http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html